# YouTube data quotas - How to increase?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm searching a way to increase the quotas of YouTube Data API but I don't see any consistent answers about that. Maybe somebody here can help me?
I sent the form to Google, but 7 days later I don't get any answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you requested for quota increase in this link: [YouTube Data API Quota Extension Application](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/).

Also, there is a [YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) is tool lets you estimate the quota cost for an API query. All API requests, including invalid requests, incur a quota cost of at least one point.